# MouseEvent swallowed if element hidden by css

Tags: javascript, css, mouseevent

I have a element (it is an icon) with `onClick` event. I want to show that element only if certain criteria is met and I'm able to read that criteria and handle the show/hide completely from CSS.

If the element is visible and I click on it, I want it to make two actions:

1. trigger JS event,
2. hide the element.

But CSS hides the element somehow quicker than JS can respond and the event is simply not triggered.

I did not studied how the the event system in JS works, but it seems to me, that firstly the CSS is resolved and then the JS event system receives info about click event on certain `x/y` position, where the element is no more, so the event is not triggered.

I tried several CSS options to hide the element including this CSS properties:

```
display: block / none;
visibility: visible / hidden;
z-index: 1 / -1;
width|height: auto / 0;
top|left|right|bottom: 0 / -9999px;
```

If I hide the element with `opacity: 1 / 0`, the event *is* triggered, because the element remains clickable in place, where it resides, but that is also problem, because I do not want the element to be clickable if not visible.

Is there any hack, how to hide element via pure CSS and at the same time trigger event on it?

I tried delay the CSS with `transition: all 160ms;`, but the CSS rules, that hides the element, are instant (you cannot transition `display`, `visibility` or `z-index`) so this had no use.

I challenge this problem in Google Chrome 53.0.2785.116 platform Win10 x64

### EDIT : [`JSBin`](https://jsbin.com/dubuqevanu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: can you please add more code, specifically the code that is doing the click handling

Comment: @finalfreq: I test it with just `addEventListener('click', console.log.bind(console))`

Comment: https://jsbin.com/muvewitono/edit?html,js,output this bin shows that basic functionality working, element is hidden and console log occurs

Comment: `But CSS hides the element somehow` - no it doesn't, there is no 'click' pseudo class, so how can CSS do anything in response to a click?

Comment: `Google Chrome 3.0.2785.116` - are you sure about that?

Comment: `I test it with just` - that wont hide anything - how is the element being hidden?

Comment: Use JavaScript to `return false` on any Events you don't want to fire.

Comment: @JaromandaX op probably meant 53.0.2785.116 which is the current version

Comment: even if you hide it and then fire an event in that order intentionally it will work.  Check it out https://jsfiddle.net/sdqfbeu0/

Comment: THis is one of those problems that need a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from the OP as the stated problem can not be duplicated by anyone

Comment: @dlkulp I've added JSBin to my question where I present my problem more clearly. Although it is possible to solve my problem through JS (e.g `jQuery.click() and jQuery.hide()`), I'm curious to solve the problem the way I've presented.

Comment: You are a victim of `Logic Error`

Comment: I wrote an answer, but delete it because it's wrong. Sooooo hard

Comment: mousedown instead of click? or display block if element is hovered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with click is when the item is hidden, the click action can not be completed. So you can switch to mousedown instead of click

```js
document.getElementById("test_click").addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
});
```

```css
#test_container {
      position: relative; 
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #test_click {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      left: 100%;
      top: 50%;
    }
    
    #test_input:focus + #test_click {
      display: inline;
    }
    
    #test_input:focus + #test_click:hover {
      color: dodgerblue;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div id="test_container">
    <input type="text" id="test_input" placeholder="focus me...">
    <span id="test_click">CLICK</span>
  </div>
  
  <h3>Click on the input and "CLICK" appears, click on "CLICK" and "CLICK" hides and no JS event is triggered although it is attached. Then, remove "display: none;" from CSS and try click again, the JS event is triggered.</h3>
```

or add css to keep element visible when hovered

```js
document.getElementById("test_click").addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
});
```

```css
#test_container {
      position: relative; 
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #test_click {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      left: 100%;
      top: 50%;
    }
    

    #test_click:hover,
    #test_input:focus + #test_click {
      display: inline;
    }
    
    #test_input:focus + #test_click:hover {
      color: dodgerblue;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div id="test_container">
    <input type="text" id="test_input" placeholder="focus me...">
    <span id="test_click">CLICK</span>
  </div>
  
  <h3>Click on the input and "CLICK" appears, click on "CLICK" and "CLICK" hides and no JS event is triggered although it is attached. Then, remove "display: none;" from CSS and try click again, the JS event is triggered.</h3>
```

Comment: WOW! You are a life saver!

Comment: The event needed to be triggered earlier, so the `onMouseDown` did the trick. After some test in [`JSBin`](https://jsbin.com/gapivayovi/edit?html,js,output), I've realized, that `blur` event is triggered long before `click`. In my scenario, the order is `mousedown --> (3 ms) --> blur --> (4 ms) --> mouseup --> (0 ms) --> click`.